# не сохраняеться значение в форме после ошибки

Tags: form

Такая фигня ребята.
Если поле "имя" заполнено, а сообщение нет, то значение "имя" сохраняется.
А если имя НЕ заполнено, а сообщение да, то после ошибки, поле "Сообщение" не сохраняет $_POST['msg'];
В чем причина?

```
$msg_box = "";
if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['msg']) && $_SESSION['antiflood'] < time())
{
    $msg = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['msg'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')) ;
    $name = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')) ;
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ;
    $errors = array();
if ($name=='') {$errors[] = 'Пусте імя';}
if ($msg=='') {$errors[] = 'Ви дуже мало написали про себе';}
if(empty($errors))
        {
            //тут добавляем в БД запись
                    }
else
        {
            $msg_box = "";
            foreach($errors as $one_error)
            {
                $msg_box .= "<span style='color: red;'>$one_error</span><br/>";
            }
        }
}







    <div class="col-12 col-12-xsmall">
        <input type="text" name="name" value="<?if (isset($name)) echo $name;?>" placeholder="Ім`я" />
    </div>
<div class="col-12">
    <textarea name="msg" value="<?if (isset($msg)) echo $msg;?>" placeholder="Напишить про себе"></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У тега textarea нет свойства value http://htmlbook.ru/html/textarea
Текст записывается между открывающим и закрывающим тегом

```
<textarea name="msg" placeholder="Напишить про себе">
    <?if (isset($msg)) echo $msg;?>
</textarea>
```

Comment: Ой дебил я) Спасибо!!!